# Integrating Mahout project with Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mahout

How do I integrate Mahout with my intellij IDE.
I have downloaded the "apache-mahout-distribution-0.13.0" from http://mahout.apache.org/.

I am finding it difficult to integrate this for my machine learning project.

Comment: Please create a maven project and add it as a depdenency in your pom.xml

Comment: Is it required to create a maven project?

Comment: You can also use SBT

Comment: IntelliJ can build without a pom.xml or build.sbt. In which case you tell IntelliJ your dependencies but I'd suggest letting IntelliJ read your build files instead as suggested above. Not sure if the distribution artifact contains source files, if not download Mahout source and configure IntelliJ to look for source wherever you put it. Each dependency has config for where to find source and binary in the IntelliJ project settings.